# Go to Ubuntu localhost from Windows XP in VirtualBox

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox, localhost, ubuntu-14.04

I using Ubuntu 14.04, but I want to test my website in Internet Explorer, I install VirtualBox, create image for Windows XP. I have a connection to Internet, but I cant go to http://localhost/. I try to found solutions, switching beetween connecton types (e.g NAT, Network Bridge), but localhost still unavailable. Maybe someone can give me some advice?

Answer (score 0):

Did you install VirtualBox's Guest Additions for Windows XP? 
Update Windows XP. Update to Internet Explorer 8. 
This video shows how to install Guest Additions in Windows XP.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9EMvQqBCBqY
Notice "Continue Anyway" is clicked several times.

Comment: I solve this by add localhos with my IP into C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file